# Private Python API key when using Angular for frontend

Tags: python, security, angularjs, authentication

I have a server implementing a python API. I am calling functions from a frontend that uses Angular.js. Is there any way to add an authentication key to my calls so that random people cannot see the key through the Angular exposed code? Maybe file structure? I am not really sure.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you send the sensitive data outside, you are at risk. You can obfuscate your code so that first grade malicious users have a hard time finding the key, but basically breaking your security is just a matter of time as an attacker will have all the elements to analyse your protocol and exchanged data and design a malicious software that will mimic your original client.

One possible (although not unbreakable) solution would be to authenticate the users themselves so that you keep a little control over who is accessing the data and revoke infected accounts.